# How to Dump multiple Variables to Excel file in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have data in 3 variable , I am able to dump this in file excel but it comes under Single Column instead of Multiple Columns, Any idea how can I get in Multiple Column

```
  - name: Add mappings to /etc/hosts
    lineinfile:
         insertafter: EOF
         dest: ~/test.xlxs
         line: "\t {{ item.0 }} \t\t {{ item.1 }} \t\t {{ item.2 }}"

    with_together:
         - "{{ Test1 }}"
         - "{{ Test2 }}"
         - "{{ Test3 }}"
```

output of above :

```
Column1
a b c
```

Expected Output :

```
Column1 Column Colum3
a       b       c
```

Comment: This should work as expected. What is in those variables `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`?

Comment: I have following Values :  Test1=a , Test2=b , Test3=c . Problem is when it gives output in csv file , it print all values under 1 column only like Column1 : a b c  , I need each value in Column1 a , Column2 b , Column3 c

Comment: I have updated my question in Proper Format , So it would be easy for you :)

Comment: Sorry, unable to reproduce. It produces the expected output. What is your operating system and how are you viewing the `test.csv` file?

Comment: are you able to produce a  b c in 3 Seperate Columns ? When you open this csv file in Excel you will notice a b c output is coming under 1 Column only , it is not coming under 3 Seperate Column .

Comment: Ah, that is the issue. Just open the file in a text editor. To open  a tab delimited file in excel, you have to fix some of its settings.

Comment: Requirement is I need output in Excel Format Only :) , Is there a way to get this output in Excel in the format I am Expecting ?

Comment: Can you update the question accordingly?

Comment: sure just updated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task will produce a TSV file, which can be imported into Excel by changing the delimiter to Tab in `Data >> Text to Columns`. You can refer this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-1-open-a-tsv-file-into-excel/3396cf11-8b91-4b7a-a327-3d60d9cc640e?tab=AllReplies#tabs) for the steps.

Else, you can create a CSV file which Excel should not have any trouble importing into its cells.

Just change the `\t` to `,` in your task,

```
  - name: Add mappings to /etc/hosts
    lineinfile:
         insertafter: EOF
         dest: ~/test.csv
         line: "{{ item.0 }},{{ item.1 }},{{ item.2 }}"

    with_together:
         - "{{ Test1 }}"
         - "{{ Test2 }}"
         - "{{ Test3 }}"
```